# Bluetooth in guest Windows with VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, bluetooth

How to grant my guest Windows XP access to the Bluetooth device?

My host OS id Ubuntu 9, and Bluetooth works there, but Windows doesn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it will work, dude. However, if you have a USB dongle with a bluetooth transmitter, your chances are better. At least VMWare workstation is able to "forward" a USB device from host go guest. I've only tried this on Windows as a host with VMWare workstation.

Comment: I've done this from a linux host and it works there as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to your problem on the Ubuntu forums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7603235

Comment: This is a description of how to use a USB connected bluetooth device. It's a lot easier in more modern versions of virtualbox, and it won't work for a non-USB internal bluetooth device. There's a good clear outline on the USB solution here: http://askubuntu.com/a/25600/6665